# drag and scroll script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a scrolling calendar script using jquery (similar to the one on an iPad)

So, I want to record the yPosition of the mousedown and the mouseup and move a div accordingly. I tried recording the mouse positions using two variables, one to be recorded on the mousedown event and one to be recorded on a mouseup event...

but right now the problem is that the variable value is not carried through, so on the mouseup the value of the mousedown is back to 0. what would I do to carry the value?

Thanks a lot in advance!

The code is below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var yStart = 0;
var yEnd = 0;
$("#year").mousedown (function(e){
    var yStart = e.pageY;
    $(".yStart").text (yStart +"ho"+ yEnd);
    }).mouseup (function(e){
        var yEnd = e.pageY;
        $(".yEnd").text (yStart +"ho"+ yEnd);
    });
    if (yStart>yEnd) {
    $("#year ul").animate({top:'-='+liHeight},"fast");  
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope in Javascript is by function. The yStart you use in the mousedown function is different than the yStart you use in the mouseup function. The mouseup function's yStart will always be zero because it is the yStart that is defined at the beginning of your script, outside the event binding. You should get rid of the "var" before yStart in your mousedown function, so instead of creating a new local variable by that name, it writes the new value to yStart and it can be used in the other function. You should also get rid of the "var" declaration in the mouseup function for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm really new to this.. but do u know where I'm suppose to declare the variable? Because getting rid of that gives me an error that says that the yStart and yEnd var is not declared.

Comment: nvm I got it now! Thanks very much.